# induction with recursive elements $y_{k}=y_{k-1}+k^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recurrence-relations, recursion

the problem is $y_{k}=y_{k-1}+k^2$, for all integers k $>=$ 2
given $y_{1}=1$

Honestly I got caught up with this question

$y_{2}=1+2^2 = 1+4 = 5$

$y_{k+1}=y_{k}+(k+1)^2$    -plugging in $y_{k}$

$y_{k+1}=y_{k-1}+k^2+(k+1)^2$    - foiling out $(k+1)^2$

$y_{k+1}=y_{k-1}+k^2+k^2+2k+1$

I have no clue where to go from here or if i'm even on the right track if anyone can give me some help it would be appreciated thank you

Comment: Hint: $y_k$ is a cubic polynomial in $k$, guess the coefficients and then prove that by induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $y_{k}=y_{k-1}+k^2$, so
\begin{eqnarray*}
y_{k}=k^2+(k-1)^2+ \cdots+ 1 =\sum_{i=1}^{k} i^2 =\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

In general, in any equation of the form
$$y_k-y_{k-1}=f(k)$$
you can sum on both sides to get
$$y_n-y_0=\sum_{k=1}^n f(k),$$
Via telescopic property at the lhs.